# puzzling behaviour of zlib.gunzip() function

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have some code that looks like this:

```
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import zlib from 'zlib';
import transform from './transform.mjs';

const s3 = new S3Client({ });

export const s3JsonLoggerHandler = async (event, context) => {
  const bucket = event.detail.bucket.name;
  const s3key = event.detail.object.key;
  let response = await s3.send(new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: s3key
  }));
  const bytes = await response.Body.transformToByteArray();
  //console.log(zlib);
  await zlib.gunzip(bytes, (err,data) => {
    const jsonData = JSON.parse(data.toString());
    if(err) throw err;
    transform(bucket, s3key, jsonData);
  });
  console.debug('Complete!');
};
```

This code doesn't work (nothing happens in the handler of `zlib.gunzip`) unless I uncomment the line `//console.log(zlib);`. When the line is commented as shown above, the `zlib.gunzip` does nothing. How is this possible???

**UPDATE**

After additional testing I noticed that actually the code alternates randomly between working and not working, regardless of whether the `console.log(zlib)` line is active!

**UPDATE2**

I tried creating a unit test. I get the error `Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?`

Comment: For one, `zlib.gunzip()` doesn't return a promise so your `await` isn't doing what you assume it does (i.e. waiting for `gunzip` to complete).

Comment: @robertklep that part is very confusing. There is a `gunzip` and a `gunzipSync`. That led me to believe that `gunzip` is async. Otherwise why would there be two of them? Anyway, I'm going to try using `gunzipSync` instead.

Comment: It _is_ asynchronous, but it doesn't return a promise (it uses a callback).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting the last part of the code to use `gunzipSync` instead of `await gunzip` fixes the problem, but I don't understand why.